# How do I create and send meeting emails and invitations from Outlook JS Add-In?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

Currently working on an Add-In for Outlook that should be able to send meeting invitations and emails. I have not found this functionality at all in the Outlook Add-In tutorials, but have found it in REST API tutorials. Do I have to implement REST API authentication inside my Add-In? If so, where shall I store authentication data (tokens)?

Already tried tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/addin-tutorial
and read through the reference here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api
but that only seems to be able to GET data from current items.

Comment: Check out [this repository](https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/tree/master/RestCaller)

Comment: We don't have outlook add-in JS APIs to achieve send functionality. With REST APIs, you can achieve more. The repository ( https://github.com/OfficeDev/outlook-add-in-command-demo/tree/master/RestCaller ) in the above comment gives you options to get & update the content too. 
Can you explain more about what you want to achieve, so that I can help you better ?

Answer (score 2):

Currently outlook add-in JS API to achieve send functionality is not a part of the product. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our [user-voice page](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins). Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered when we go through our planning process.

Comment: Hi @Outlook add-ins Team,
Is this feature available in current build? as it more than 2 years now.
Thanks